# Eval in JavascriptEngine takes "a-gamma" as separate variables?is there any solution for this?

Tags: javascript-engine

I am trying to store the variables as

```
 e.put("a",3);
 e.put("a-gamma",4);
 eval("a+a-gamma");
```

But on evaluation it throws the exception that gamma not defined in variables.
Is there any solution for this? . i am stuck!

Comment: "a-gamma" isn't a valid name in JavaScript. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: @dystroy i am trying to add two variables "a" and "a-gamma" using javascriptengine eval method in java.

Comment: You can't have a variable named "a-gamma". Change it to a property using an object or simply choose a valid name. And please precise what js engine you're using.

Comment: @dystroy i am using ScriptEngine